# Flex 3 - Equals sign (=) in TextInput control Is displaying as a plus sign (+) in Firefox

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

When I deploy my Flex application and browse to it in Firefox (3.0.8), typing an equals sign into a TextInput control results in a plus sign.

In Chrome and IE, an equals sign works as expected.  Also, when I run the Flex project locally in Firefox, the equals sign works properly.

I have tried deploying the SWF on a different server but the equals symbol is still being converted to a plus sign in Firefox.

Here is the CSS applied to the TextInput control:

```
TextInput
{
   color: #333333; 
   fontSharpness:"200"; 
   fontAntiAliasType:"advanced"; 
   fontSize: 12; 
   font-family: Arial, "Hiragino Kaku Gothic Pro", "ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", "ＭＳ Ｐゴシック", sans-serif; 
}
```

Besides CSS, there have been no other modifications to the control.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=347185)/Flash. If you disable wmode=transparent, it should work as expected.

Comment: Although we can not use this solution (we need the wmode of the swf to be transparent), this appears to be the only fix for this issue.  Arg!

Answer (score 0):

What is the language encoding in Firefox? Are you using a different keyboard layout? This sounds like a problem with the Firefox configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using wmode and transparency along with components in Flex/AS3 you can also work around the issue by forcing the stage to render.

See the Stage Events:

```
stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RENDER))
```

Comment: We need transparency so disabling wmode=transparent is not an option.  I tried to add the Event.RENDER call to the creationComplete event of the component but it did not fix the issue.  I also added it to the creationComplete event of the application but no luck.  I found this issue in the Adobe bug system (http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FP-688).  Looks like it will be fixed in the next release of Firefox.  Any other thoughts on a workaround for the time being?

Comment: I've had a similar problem, the only difference was that I wasn't using any Japanese characters and since I don't have direct experience embedding foreign language characters I can't concretely say that isn't part of the issue.

In my case, I would add the RENDER event whenever I resized or changed the text of the field -- I believe that will work better than on creationComplete.

Comment: Added stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RENDER)) to bot the change and resize events on the textInput.  Still no luck.  We are looking at changing the design of our html page so that wmode=transparent is not required.  Also, hopefully the next version of FireFox will fix this.  Thanks for everyone's help!